# Why does PHP remove the space after the first word when returning a string in a function

Tags: php, function

For some reason, the space after the first word is removed when returning a string in a php function. I can't figure out why.

```
function something() {
   $string = "My sentence looks like this";
   return $string;
}

function something_else() {
   $output = something();
   echo $output;
}
```

Outputs "Mysentence looks like this"

Edit: 
If I add `echo $string;` after line 2 it prints `$string` correctly. However, the second function does not output it that way.

Also, I am able to get it working by changing line 2 to

```
$string = "<strong>My sentence</strong looks like this";
```

Comment: [This is working for me](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1abc4251bfab8ef480f6ef7ab6d17399399e2346)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This code also works for me, there must be something else on your end that is causing the missing space. If you try to explain your production environment (such as OS, PHP version, execution method etc) someone may be able to use their experience to spot what might be causing this. Good luck finding the issue :)

Comment: I am using PHP7.x on Debian 8. Running it on a Apache web server. @WilliamPatton see my edit above.

Comment: I tested on PHP7.1 with Ubuntu 16.04 and still get correct output. I do not know what to suggest, I hope someone else can come by and give you an answer because this is very unusual :s

Comment: @WilliamPatton I'm a little lost where to even diagnose. I already confirmed the `$string` does not have any odd characters because it outputs within it's own function correctly. For some reason the second function strips the space after the first character. Changing the text to something else causes the same thing to happen.

Comment: @WilliamPatton So somewhere in the second function I did a copy & paste and apparently it affected it. Very, very odd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing various browsers, the issue seems related to MS Edge only. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE.

Comment: Can you explain the cause of the problem and have you found a work around? Right now the question is non reproducible for us and the answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, probably you can check for "hidden" chars that can alter the output, depending on the editor you are using, search for "show hidden chars in $editor".

Comment: To clarify, it works if I echo the $string in the `something` function. So there's no hidden chars. When outputting from the function in the original post it removes the space.