# Why is the string output using echo PHP missing the space after the first word when opened in MS Edge?

Tags: php, apache, echo

When I run the php script the space is removed automatically from the string printed using echo.

I tried to use echo somewhere else and the space is there. Only in this case the space is removed. 
[Why does PHP remove the space after the first word when returning a string in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844853/why-does-php-remove-the-space-after-the-first-word-when-returning-a-string-in-a)
someone said that the problem is with the MS edge browser. It is true, the code works in IE. but still why does it not work in MS edge but sometimes does?

```
<?php 
    if (date("D") == "Fri"){
        echo "Have a nice weekend!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Have a nice day!";
    }
?>
```

I expected `Have a nice day!` , but the output is `Havea nice day!`

why is the first space not showing?!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it show up in "view source"? Try removing the entire string and typing it manually; perhaps you've copy/pasted some sort of hidden character.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It [works](https://imgur.com/a/aa9xKOy) on my computer. Can you give us relevant code part to reproduce it?

Comment: @Cid Did you use Edge? That's where the problem occurs.

Comment: ok it worked in MS edge when I used <html> tags

Comment: Worked on edge without html tags for me

Comment: @Barmar yes, that is an edge screenshot (no html tag)

Comment: but still it doesn't work in ms edge without html tags but in IE it does. Why only the first space?

Comment: If it works with HTML tags and not without, it's presumably some sort of bug. Use proper HTML5 markup and carry on.

Comment: This shouldn't be browser related the datas sent are the same. As stated @ceejayoz this is certainly wrong character used as space.

Comment: *"it's presumably some sort of bug"*. Greatest comment ever :D

Comment: @firangi : right click on the page and view source please.

Comment: I used VS code to write php script

Comment: @firangi on Edge I meant

Comment: It's probably related to encoding/charset/string parsing

Comment: @Cid I just added screenshots in the question

Comment: @firangi I'd again encourage you to view source in your browser - **not** the inspector, as that shows post-processed HTML, but the view source option in the browser's menu (or use cURL or something). What shows up there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your Code within the HTML Tags to make it work.
Otherwise the Browser tries to "wrap" some kind of HTML around it automatically - which is some kind of buggy.

The following would work just fine:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php 
       if (date("D") == "Fri"){
           echo "Have a nice weekend!";
       }
       else {
           echo "Have a nice day!";
       }
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```